# Attack From All Sides

Tags: vocabulary, military

Is there a term in Latin for an attack from all sides, similar to the English *gauntlet*? I need the translation to be as short-and-sweet as possible, as it's for a short title: *The Gauntlet* (that's it). A singular word for this would be much better than a multiple-term description.

Comment: The Romans seem to have considered an attack on all sides to be akin to flooding.  The verb used is circumfundo -ere. See Lewis & Short. L.: circumfunduntur hostes, Cs.: equites ab lateribus circumfusi, L.: hostes undique circumfusi erant. Does this give you any ideas?

Comment: Modern usage of [The Gauntlet](http://www.historyadventuring.com/2015/04/the-gauntlet-clint-eastwood-in-phoenix.html), just for fun!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Might I suggest *undique*. It's an adverb literally meaning "from all sides," and is quite often used in military contexts, such as the example below given from Lewis and Short:

> from all parts, sides, or places, from every quarter, on all sides, on every part, everywhere: "ut **undique** uno tempore in hostes impetus fieret," Caes. *B. G.* 1, 22

Comment: This certainly works for "from all sides," but I don't think it can be plugged into the OP's use case. Part of the confusion is that a "gauntlet" is pretty different from an "attack from all sides."

Comment: @brianpck Yeah, I'm interpreting his want creatively. I think *undique* appropriately gets the idea of "from all sides" down with an implicit "attack" making sense in the book, though it's not a gauntlet per se. Gauntlet's also can mean "extreme trial," though, and if MSH is as young as I suspect he is, he might have Harry Potter on his mind.

Comment: I put a comment up above before I saw this answer.  In Livy & other authors there are constructions like this ablative absolute: "circumfuso undique equitatu" -- having been flooded on all sides by the cavalry. I wonder if something about this idea of flooding would be useful for the questioner's purpose.  It's not a gauntlet idea at all, but these overwhelming attacks were the reason the army formed an "orbis" or a "testudo" for protection.

Comment: It's a good answer, @Palizsche, and I recommend turning it into a full answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 10):

A "gauntlet" (as in "running the gauntlet") refers to a specific form of punishment, whereby someone goes between two rows of men while being struck at.

A close Roman equivalent is the [*fustuarium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfustuarium) ([Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fustuarium)), which is:

> a cudgelling to death, a military punishment for desertion or other capital offences

As far as I know, a gauntlet is more a form of punishment than execution, but this may still be a helpful starting point.

Comment: I must have read both Cicero's Philippics and Livy book 5 combined a dozen times, but this word, and what it actually means, never really stuck out. What an interesting (and gruesome) image!